# How can I add a line in deedy resume - latex overleaf

Tags: overleaf

[image]

In the pic above, I want to add a line "candidate for computer science", however I am not sure how to do it. For example -

I tried putting "`candidate for computer science \\`" but it throws me an error and I cant see rest of the resume.

I used \ since I needed a new line

[image]

How should I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Rather that posting screenshots can you please post your code. This way people can cut-and-paste the code to troubleshoot your problem. Ideally, you should post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). That is, a minimal piece of compilable code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: There is no error shown for the code you have visible in the screenshots, but the extra line in the header has caused the rest of the CV to be pushed to the second page. If you remove one line of content from each column it will again fit on one page. But as Andrew mentioned, it's best if you post your code here so we don't have to reconstruct what you did based on the Overleaf template and your screenshots.